# What is a fixed point integer?

Tags: types, integer, fixed-point

In http://microformats.org/wiki/hreview-aggregate

it says:

> **rating**. required. fixed point integer [1.0-5.0], with optional alternate worst (default:1.0) and/or best (default:5.0), also fixed point integers, and explicit average.

What is a fixed point integer?  Maybe that means integer?  Why is 1.0 or 2.5 or 5.0 also called a "fixed point integer"?  Because integer has no decimal part.

Answer (score 4):

As cdhowie said, they likely mean fixed point *number*

To answer you question with that adjustment to the original statement, a fixed point number is one with a finite amount of decimal precision. This precision is guaranteed. If you may or may not be aware, floating point numbers used a complex approximation system to store the value which leads to the interesting results you sometimes see. 1.01 for example actually evaluating as 1.00999999999999998

A fixed point value has guaranteed accuracy to a specific number of digits after the decimal.

You can find more information on theory and implementation of fixed point values here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic

Answer (score 0):

They have their terminology wrong.  They meant fixed-point *number*, not integer.